# Use regular expression to match "≈"

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I want to use regular expression O.\w*≈\b (in c#, .NET Framework 4.0) to match the string like `"O.Hasdaas≈"` , but it fails. However, if I use it to match `"O.Hasdaas≈abc"` , it can recognize `"O.Hasdaas≈"` . Does anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: On a quick glance it appears to be related to the word-boundary. What happens with using `(?:$|\b)`, which will match end-of-input *or* a word-boundary, instead of just `\b`?

Comment: Given "O.Hasdaas≈abc" as input, do you want the match to fail? Remember that the regex will match if it finds the pattern anywhere within your input string.  If you want to match the entire input string, you should use "^O.\w*≈$" as your regex.

Comment: @JoelLee I want to match "O.Hasdaas≈" in "O.Hasdaas≈abc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because of the word boundary `\b` you have at the end of your regular expression. A word boundary does not consume any characters, it asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

If you want to match `O.Hasdaas≈` and not `O.Hasdaas≈abc`, you could use a non-word boundary.

```
O\.\w*≈\B
```

Or you can simply remove the word boundary to match both of your examples.

```
O\.\w*≈
```

Comment: +1 Described in [Regular Expression Language:Anchors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions)